# convert string to list of dictionaries in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a string like this:

```
"[{cidr: 192.168.5.240/24, nic: ETH5}, {cidr: 192.168.5.241/24, nic: ETH0}, {cidr: 192.168.5.243/24, nic: ETH5.2}]"
```

I want to convert it to a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{"cidr": "192.168.5.240/24", "nic": "ETH5"}, {"cidr": "192.168.5.241/24", "nic": "ETH0"}, {"cidr": "192.168.5.243/24", "nic": "ETH5.2"}]
```

Is there a clear and simple way to do it in python?

Comment: I assume that the ',' and '}' characters can't occur in the values? It's a bit of a hard to deal with format you have there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one approach using regex and `ast` module.

**Ex:**

```
import re
import ast

data = "[{cidr: 192.168.5.240/24, nic: ETH5}, {cidr: 192.168.5.241/24, nic: ETH0}, {cidr: 192.168.5.243/24, nic: ETH5.2}]"
data = re.sub(r"(\w+):\s*([A-Za-z0-9./]+)", r'"\1":"\2"', data)   #encapsulate string with quotes. 
print(ast.literal_eval(data))
```

**Output:**

```
[{'cidr': '192.168.5.240/24', 'nic': 'ETH5'},
 {'cidr': '192.168.5.241/24', 'nic': 'ETH0'},
 {'cidr': '192.168.5.243/24', 'nic': 'ETH5.2'}]
```